# Take multiple stratified samples from

Tags: sampling, stratification, treatment

I am interested in taking three separate stratified samples from a population so that I can assign them to different treatments. I see some obvious issues with this, namely being that elements in the first sample don't have the chance of being in the second sample, etc. Is there a good way to achieve this result?

Comment: Please explain what you mean exactly by "taking" and "achieve this result." Are you asking about the logistics of conducting a stratified sampling program?  Of how to estimate a population property based on a stratified sample?  Of how to demonstrate there are "issues"?  How to find an optimal design for a stratified sampling program? Something else?